# LG Mini Split AC Error Code CH05

Tags: hvac

LG Mini Split
LMAN125HVT
Errot Code CH05

1. All wires good and making connections
2. There are two indoor units attached to the outdoor unit (Unit A and Unit B)
3. Unit B works and Unit A shows an error code of CH05
4. There are 3 wires between the outside unit and each of the indoor units
5. 1 (L1) Black, 2 (L2) Red, 3A White, 3B White
6. The voltage between the wires are as follows
   a.  L1 and 3B- 240VAC (working unit)
   b.  L2 and 3B- 0 VAC (working unit)
   c.  L1 and 3A- 125VAC (Error Code CH05)
   d.  L2and 3A- 125VAC (Error Code CH05)
7. The same readings are obtained on the indoor units

Answer (score 3):

From [LG Air Conditioning - Universal Split Fault Codes Sheet](http://www.matairconditioning.com/img/manuals/Fault-Codes-Multi-CAC.pdf)

> Fault Code 05 These error codes indicate a communication fault between
> the indoor and outdoor units; it appears approximately 5 minutes after
> powering up the system. The communication between the units is a
> fluctuating DC voltage commonly called a serial signal, it can be
> easily lost if the wiring is not done correctly. If there is a
> communication error fault CH05 will appear on the Wired Remote within
> 5 mins of powering up the system.

Download the above reference to check and fix the wiring, which should be fairly easy to do... It's *much* better news than having to find and fix a refrigerant leak!